# Android Studio - Media Player: How do i prevent sound from overlapping?

Tags: android-studio, android-mediaplayer

```
package com.example.sound;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sound();
            }
        });

    }

    public  void sound()
    {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mesa);
        mp.start();
    }
    
}
```

Right now, when i press the button WHILE the audio is playing, the second audio comes on and overlaps the first audio.

If i spam the button, there will be a lot of audio overlapping each other.

I only want one audio to be played at a single time. The first audio should stop if i press the button again.

How can i do this?  I have seen some other relevant post but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public  void sound()
{
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mesa);
    mp.start();
}
```

seems like you are creating a new instance of MediaPlayer each time the user clicks the button - thats why you hear multiple sounds. You should create a global instance of MediaPlayer, then in onClick method  you should stop already played audio and start a new one.

Comment: @yarn glad to hear that, please accept the answer as a correct one if that was the problem indeed